# Channels current state is disconnected(laravel-websocket on ubuntu Host server)

Tags: ubuntu, php, websocket, laravel

I am working on Laravel-websocket package i got stucked on this error from quite long time.

i have configure basic laravel procject along with laravel websocket package on my local ubuntu as well as digitalocen ubuntu host server.I did same configuration on both places.On my local service working like a charm but on my host server it is not at all working.I have tried so many option but no luck i am mentioning My config file of my host server

broadcasting.php

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host'  => '<domain-url>',
                'post'  => 6001,
                'scheme'    => 'http'
```

websockets.php:-

```
  'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],

 'ssl' => [
        'local_cert' => null,

        'local_pk' =>  null,


        'passphrase' =>  null,
    ],
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=chat
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=abcd
PUSHER_APP_KEY=abcd
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=abcd
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

/resource/js/bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

 window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

 window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: 'my-key',
     wsHost: window.location.hostname,
     wsPort: 6001,
     wssPort: 6001,
     disableStats: true,

 });
```

above all my configs but i don;\'t know why i am getting the above error.Can anyone help me out of this
note: i have allowed port 6001 on my server

thanks in advance